# HTML: how to use a href to link to a file name that starts with # character

Tags: html, fragment-identifier

I have many text files, the name of which starts with # (hash) sign. It would be very cumbersome to rename the files.

If I try to link to the text files in an HTML file, using `<a href="#example.txt">` the browser interprets the leading # character as a "fragment identifier".

My requirement is for the link to open the text file in the browser.

I have tried substituting the leading # character like this:

```
<a href="#35;example.txt"> 
<a href="#&23;example.txt">
```

but that does not work (the text file is not opened).

Is there an HTML work-around, or is JavaScript required for this?

Comment: My examlpe code was not posted. Should be  a href="&35;example.txt" and  a href="&#23;example.txt"

Comment: First thing first, the filename of a file that is used in a website should not contain `#`. You MUST rename it.

Comment: Would rename if possible, many of the files are being generated in an application that is not able to be changed.

Comment: A simple bash program would rename all the files for you once you run it. I believe there's plenty of them on the internet so give it a try maybe

Comment: More a StackOverflow advice.... check out the `?`  icon in the question editor for some tips on how to include code in your quesion. I've edited the question so your code is visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem -**

`href` with a `#` in front of the file name fails to load the file. This is because you need to **URL Encode** the symbol.

**Solution -**

Use `%23` which is the URL Encoding for `#`.

**Example -**

If you want to use an `href` to link a file named `#test.html`, you would do this -

```
<a href="%23test.html">Click Me!</a>
```

**Recommendation -**

**Do not use file names with `#` in the name.**

If you want to rename all of the files in the directory you are working in, here is a bash script that will do that for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

target="/home/user/directory/change/$1"
for f in "$target"/*
do
    letter=$(basename $f | cut -c1-1)
    if [ "$letter" == "#" ]; then
        withoutHash=$(basename $f | cut -c 2-)
        mv  $f $withoutHash
    fi 
done
```

This bash script should be easy to understand but there is surely some one liner on Stack Overflow. Try setting up a test directory and playing with it. You could pretty easily figure out how to traverse sub directories if needed.

Comment: A big NO. Though URL encoding can solve the problem, such file name should NOT be used on any website.

Comment: The OP did not ask the best practice to name files, they asked why they could not get their href to work given the examples they tried. The example I showed clearly is the only way to make it work. Sure, I recommend they change the file names which is why I provided a bash script to automate that for the OP.

Comment: if `rename` command is available, you can use `rename -v 's/^#//' *.txt`

Comment: Yes, I see all of the answers on SO. 1, rename does not come installed on Ubuntu (assuming they would have to install it on the OP OS) so that can be a little more confusing and I figured this was pretty easy for the OP to understand as opposed to copying and pasting that one liner in.

Comment: Also, that command you are showing only handles .txt files.

Comment: For reference, file system is on IBM i (AS/400,  iSeries). I am not allowed change access to the file system, read-only. In mainframe/midrange environments (EBCDIC), it is not uncommon to have file names that start with #. If the application was under my control, I would change it, but it is what it is. When the file names are generated, they start with # symbol. When put into the file system, the EBCDIC is converted to ASCII.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @CraigPelkie, I hope this helps then. %23 should be all you need!

Comment: Thank you wuno, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to do it you can try with replacing `"#"` with `%23`. It should work.

You will avoid lots and lots and lots of pain if you are able to rename your files so they don't contain a `"#"` character.

As long as they do, you will probably have current and future cross-browser issues, confusion on behalf of future developers working on your code (or confusion on your behalf in the future, when you've forgotten the ins and outs of the encoding), etc.

Also, some Unix/Linux systems don't allow "#" in filenames. Not sure what OS you're using, but your filenames should be as portable as possible across OSs, even if you're "sure" right now that you'll never be running on one of those systems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the # in your fileNames. # means an id and the browser thinks its an id and looks for it on the page.